# Regular Expression to match consecutive -. or .- (hypen and dot) in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a scenario where consecutive -. or .- should not be allowed in a URL.

Eg. `https://www.test.-nic` or `https://www.test-.nic` whereas `https://www.test.nic--xn/` should be allowed

Can you help me improve this regular expression?

```
/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*.[a-z0-9]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.-‌​*)?$/i
```

Comment: Regex should allow a url like https://www.test.nic--xn

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: "/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*.[a-z0-9]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.-*)?$/i"  This is the expression I am using as of now.

Comment: Please update the question instead of commenting

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
/^(https?|ftp):\/\/(?=.*?(?:\.-|-\.)[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.[a-z0-9]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i
```

`(?=.*?(?:\.-|-\.)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if `._` or `-.` are there in the URL.