# Regular Expression to match consecutive -. or .- (hyphen and dot) in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a scenario where consecutive -. or .- should not be allowed in a URL.

Eg. https://www.test.-nic should not be allowed whereas https://www.test.nic--xn/ should be allowed

Can you help me improve this regular expression?

```
/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*.[a-z0-9]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.-‌​*)?$/i
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382335/regular-expression-to-match-consecutive-or-hypen-and-dot-in-a-string

Comment: You do not need to create same questions. Just edit the one you had before. If it is good, it will be reopened.